# redondeo con valores decimales especificos c#

Tags: c#

Hola: quisiera ver si me pueden ayudar .
quiero redondear un valor con 2 decimales pero a un valor puntual.

por ejemplo, 
si el valor decimal es entre 0 y 0,49 queda en 0,50
si el valor decimal es entre 0,51 y 0,99 va al entero siguiente con decimal 00.

muchas gracias

Answer (score 4):

Debes usar la función [`Math.Ceiling`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Ceiling_System_Double_) de la siguiente manera si quieres redondear hacia arriba en valores de 0.5:

```
var resultado = Math.Ceiling(valor * 2) / 2;
```

O tambien:

```
var resultado = Math.Ceiling(0.22 / 0.5) * 0.5;
```

Si por ejemplo quisieras redondear hacia arriba al siguiente valor mas cercano de 0.05, sería asi:

```
var resultado = Math.Ceiling(valor * 20) / 20;
// o
var resultado = Math.Ceiling(0.22 / 0.05) * 0.05;
```

Generalizando:

```
private double RedondeoArriba (double valor, double paso)
{
     return Math.Ceiling(valor/ paso) * paso;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Utiliza el metodo [Math.Round()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.math.round)

Con esto puedes redondear un valor de tipo **Double** o **Decimal**

Ejemplo:

```
using System;

public class Sample {
   static void Main() {
      Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(3.44m, 1)); 
      Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(3.45m, 1)); 
      Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(3.46m, 1)); 
      Console.WriteLine();

      Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.34m, 1)); 
      Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.35m, 1)); 
      Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.36m, 1)); 
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       3.4
//       3.4
//       3.5
//       
//       4.3
//       4.4
//       4.4
```

Comment: esto no hace lo que el quiere...

Comment: Por que no? Que sugieres?

Comment: 3.44 segun OP deberia ir a 3.50.. en tu ejemplo va a 3.4